# WebStorm search everywhere: keybinding for opening files

Tags: webstorm

I am working in Ubuntu 18.04. When I open the Search Everywhere panel with <kbd>Shift + Shift</kbd> and type the start of a filename, I see the list of found results. I can open the files by clicking on their name, but is there a keybinding to do the same action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `Enter` should open the selected file. This doesn't work in some versions due to [IDEA-200654](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200654) that is fixed in 2018.3